# Rank finding algorithm for points in 2-D space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rank

Rank finding problem: In the 2 dimension space, we shall say that a point `A=(a1,a2)` dominates a point B=(b1,b2) if and only if a1>b1 and b1>b2. Given a set of n points, the rank of a point X is the number of points dominated by X. Design an algorithm to find the rank of every point.

Answer (score 2):

Sort points by their first coordinate. Then insert them into order-statistics tree, which sorts them by second coordinate.

Rank of the point in the order-statistics tree at the time it is inserted is exactly the number of points, dominated by this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stable sort twice to sort by the first attribute and then by the second attribute. The positon in the final sorted array gives the number of points that a given point is dominating.

Answer (score 0):

The wavelet tree data structure solves this problem. I think the construction of it is essentially the same process as what Evgeny and pogo have described.